# .HTML() from multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sshg7/1/), code below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="one" style="display:none">One</div>
<div id="two" style="display:none">Two </div>
<div id="three" style="display:none">Three</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

​**jQuery:**

```
$("#output").html($("#one,#two").html());
```

I can make it work with one selector, what I am trying to do is use multiple selectors, I seem to be going about it the wrong way. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.html()` will only get the content from the first element matching the selector rule:

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched
>   elements.

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/html/*

---

If you want content from two elements you should do:

```
$("#output").html($("#one").html() + $("#two").html());
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sshg7/2/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.text()` if you only want to get text from those divs:

```
$("#output").html($("#one, #two, #three").text())
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sshg7/4/)

Comment: +1 Nice, I wasn't aware `text()` concatenated the different string values

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
$("#output").html(function() {
  var html = [];
  $("#one,#two").each(function() {
     html.push(this.innerHTML);
  });
  return html.join("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are lots of elements:

```
$("#output").html(
  $(selector_for_many_elements).map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
  }).get().join(', ');
);
```